# auto number field has duplicates

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

How is this possible?
I have a table **Contacts**, with a field **contactId**, which is Autonumber type. I ran the following query on it:

```
SELECT ContactId
FROM Contacts
GROUP BY contactId
HAVING Count(ContactId) > 1
```

And I got 9 records.

Comment: Delete the rows which contain duplicate values and then make `ContactId` the primary key.  Then no more duplicates possible.

Comment: Several reasons: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-40.html

Answer (score 2):

It is possible because you can insert any value in Autonumber field using `INSERT` SQL. After this Access will generate next number = last inserted + 1, but not = max number + 1.
In order to avoid this add primary or unique key to autonumber field.

Comment: how do I add a primary key? I thought making it autonumber is making it a primary key.

Comment: No, just adding new autonumber field doesn't make it Primary Key. It happens if you create table using wizard. In table design just select your field and click Design->Primary Key on ribbon

Comment: I can't make a new table now. How can I see if ContactId is a primary key or not? In design view, general,new value is increment. doesn't that mean it is the primary key? if not, how do I change it?

Comment: In design view you should see a yellow key sign next to the ContactID field. If you don't, click on Primary Key button on ribbon, it will add primary key to selected field(s)